# What is the slowest part of a query with date limit in where?

Tags: sql-server

Yes, it's kind of an open ended question since i'm not even remotely familiar with query performance. I'm expecting there to be some glaring reason why it might be slow, like there might be a better way to execute the date filtering. Simple table on MSSqlServer. I dont have permissions to retrieve the execution plan from SSMS. LastChg is a DateTime Type. Can't post volumes lol.

```
SELECT [fh_pkey]
      ,[fh_id]
      ,[fh_type]
      ,[fh_status]
      ,[fh_invoice_dt]
      ,[fh_ship_dt]
      ,[fh_ready]
      ,[fh_lastchg]
      ,[fh_bt_id]
  FROM [FC_MDT].[dbo].[fcfgthd]
  WHERE [fh_lastchg] > DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE())
```

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: #1... What is the actual data type of fh_lastchg? a CHAR or VARCHAR formatted to look like a date, isn't a date... #2... Is there a covering index on fcfgthd with fh_lastchg as the first key?... #3... How many rows are you trying to pull? I've got a few tables that would melt your laptop if you tried to pull 6 months worth of data at one time...

Comment: ...6 months worth of ***non aggregrated*** data  :P

Comment: I don’t use MSSqlServer, but Excel stores dates as numbers so it could be fast

Answer (score 2):

Make sure there's an index with `fh_lastchg` as the first field.

Comment: What's that going to do?

Comment: @JohnBarbour Indexes help performance by organizing the data. Think of a phone book. You can find all the people with last name Bardour but going to the B, then the Ba,then... until you find a full match; then you stop on the first mismatch. If the phone book was organized randomly, you'd need to look at every entry. Without an index on a field, the entire table/column needs searched.